# What's is the equivalent to this code in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, https, line

**Situation**

I'm tyring to send a certain message to every friend of my LINE's developer account.
I have no idea how to do that, but I already created it in PHP.
But again I don't know how to do this in C#.

Here is some information about my editor and stuff.

**Editor:** Visual Studio 2017

**Template:** I got "LINE Bot C# Template" in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pierre3.LINEBotCSharpTemplate

**Project:** I created the project with "LINEBotApplication"

**What I want to do**

I want to convert the code below to C#.

```
<?php
// HTTP REQUEST
$ch = curl_init('https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push');
$options = [
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// To execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// To check eroors
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
if ($errno) {
    return;
}

// To get HTTP status
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$httpStatus = $info['http_code'];

$responseHeaderSize = $info['header_size'];
$body = substr($result, $responseHeaderSize);

// If 200
echo $httpStatus . ' ' . $body;
```

**What I'm not sure**

I don't know how to fully convert the given code.

I may be able to convert "curl_init" method, by looking at
[How to send data using the webrequest class](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

But with the remaining code I need assistance to convert it.
If you need more, I'd love to share.

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3):

中井さん、StackOverflowへようこそ！
I don't know much about PHP, but it seems to me your code is not doing anything other than sending a simple HTTP POST request. You can achieve the same thing in C# using a WebRequest. This should help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8

EDIT:
Regarding what you asked in your comment, you can't just add the options to the WebRequest as an array like in PHP. Those API's are just different. For example you'd make a WebRequest like this

```
WebRequest myWebRequest=WebRequest.Create("https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push");
```

then instead of

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
```

You would do

```
myWebRequest.Headers.Add([header name], [header value]);
```

for every header you need to add. (Or maybe there's a way of adding a collection of headers)
And so on.

Also, in researching how to do a POST with a WebRequest, it seems quite clumsy. So you might want to use HttpClient instead. Here's more on which one to choose.
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3198673/my-two-cents-on-webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest.html

Bottom line is, it's not that straightforward to just rewrite something from PHP to C#. Those are two very different beasts. So you need to do a bit more studying.

Or maybe someone will come along and give you the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for answer.But tha link that you gave me is what i posted in my question.

Comment: But maybe my question is I don't know how to convert array in PHP to array in 
C# . I know that there is nothing like PHP's array in C#.  Mabye using Dictionary class?

Comment: I see. I didn't realize it was the same, because you posted it in Japanese.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I'm using PHP in my main project. And now I have to do some research using C#. If it's going to be my long-term job, I can do a lot more study. But thanks again for your code!!! I can work on this with some help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and C#. I haven't worked with LINE Bot but I thought I'd provide a generic example which might help understanding working with HTTP request in C#.

I have created this sample app for you as an example, using [.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com) and HttpClient. Just create a [simple console app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-with-xplat-cli) and paste the following code into `Program.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var content = new StringContent("{ \"your\": \"content\", \"maybe\": \"json\" }");
            content.Headers.Add("X-SOME-RANDOM", "header-value");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://httpbin.org/post", content);

            var httpStatus = response.StatusCode;
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($"{httpStatus} {body}");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps a bit. Have fun!

PS Thanks to [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org) for the handy service.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful code.  I have never used C# as my main language. And now I have to do some research. But I don't have any time to get in-depth knowledge about C#. but I don't know how to convert the code below.                                  
 $options = [
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
];

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with PHP but I can guess a couple of things like the 'POST' relates to the client.PostAsync call and the headers can be added using the content.Headers.Add call. The code above can be run very easily in any popular platform with just installing .NET Core 3.0. Give it a shot and trial-error etc. Good luck.